# discord.py how to delete message on a reaction from the original command user

Tags: python, discord.py

I currently have this code where if a message contains the right words (it's not using a command pre-fix), the bot will reply. The bot's message gets self-reacted with an X emoji. If it is clicked, the bot's message will be deleted. Currently, my issue is that anyone can click the X and it will delete the message. I only want it so only the user that the bot replied to originally, their react will trigger the deletion. I'm not sure on how to proceed. Is a bot.wait_for the way to go here?

In the end, it would be nice if the original user reacts to the message, both the bot's post and the original post will be deleted.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.author.id != client.user.id:
        return
    if user.id == reaction.message.mentions[0].id and reaction.emoji == "❌":
        await reaction.message.delete()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    msg = ""

    # insert code to set msg

    if msg:
        new_msg = await message.channel.send(msg)
        await new_msg.add_reaction("❌")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it was quick to code and works as intended. Basically you will store the message ID connected to its Author ID. Then by click on X you will fetch the message ID and check if the User who clicked the X got the author ID which was stored earlier. So with this code, if you write "test" you will create the message.

```
id_storage = {}
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    global id_storage  # access the global id_storage
    rid = reaction.message.id
    if reaction.message.author.id != client.user.id:
        return
    if user.id == id_storage[rid] and reaction.emoji == "❌":
        await reaction.message.delete()
        del id_storage[rid]  # remove the entry so that the storage dict doesnt get fuller and fuller

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global id_storage  # access the global id_storage
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    msg = "test"  # the code that will trigger the action
    
    if message.content == msg:  # this is only done when the message matches the code
        new_msg = await message.channel.send("Only the author can remove this message by clicking on X")
        id_storage[new_msg.id] = message.author.id  # store the message id as a key and the Author ID as a value
        await new_msg.add_reaction("❌")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well for the time being. Hopefully storage of the variable won't be an issue as some messages don't get a reaction. The bot restarts every 24 hours so I hope that will compensate.